# Copy calculated date value as real date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have calculated date ranges in excel like:

for example I have a date in B2 and substract 120 days from that like that:

[image]

When I copy the date the formula gets copied and not the date. I tried to copy and "only past values" but then I get weird values like `37953` ect.

[image]

How to only take the date value which I have calculated in my sheet. btw I am using [excel-2010](/questions/tagged/excel-2010)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use PasteSpecial > Values and Number Format (in Excel 2007 and following that's the "123%" icon

Answer (score 3):

According ti this 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/figure-out-dates-by-using-formulas-RZ006177103.aspx?section=3
Dates are stored in Excel as serial numbers starting with 1, which represents January 1, 1900. That's when the Excel calendar starts.

So, set data type of the cell you're pasting to "Date" and Excel will cast value to normal date.

OR use function =TEXT(cell;"dd.mm.yyyy")